# SugarCRM : Encrypt a field while creating report using kreport

Tags: sugarcrm

I am creating a report using kreport v3.0 in sugarcrm. The module whose report i want to create has certain confidential fields, which i do not want to show in report generated. 
So can anyone help me customize kreport so as to encrypt those field while generating report or even remove those field from kreport UI.

This is the only Documentation i found for customizing kreport.

[KReporter 3.0 Customizing Queries](http://wiki.sinergiacrm.org/images/KReporter_3.0_customizing_queries.pdf)

I am using Sugarcrm CE 6.5.

Comment: why do you add those fields in report display? hopefully, you have an option to select display columns for the report.

Comment: The problem is crm is handled by diffrent kind of role based users and all users have the option to select it, which i want to restrict. I want to make some roles access that collumn in kreport.